# how to avoid a domain call in unit testing with grails / spock

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock, grails-domain-class

I have the following lines of code

```
username = username.stripIndent()
user = User."${databaseInstance}".findByUsername(username)
if (user == null){
   return "User does not exist"
}
```

I'm trying to unit test this functionality with:

```
def setup() {
    def mockUser = Mock(User)
    myClass.user = mockUser
}

void "userNotFoundGetUserInfo"(){
    given:
    myClass.databaseInstance = 'X'
    _ * mockUser._ >> null

    when:
    def result = myClass.getUserInfo(username)

    then:
    result == "User does not exist"
}
```

but I keep getting an error of "No such property: X for class mypackage.User"

I realize this is because i'm mocking the "user" object and not the "User" class, so how do I get around the fact that my code is making a direct call to a domain class?

Comment: You need to mock the `User` class. What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

Use Grails built-in `@Mock` annotation instead of Spock's `Mock()` method. Go like:

```
@Mock(User)
class YourTestSpecification extends Specification {
    def setup() {
        myClass.user = new User()
    }
}
```

`@Mock` is meant to mock Grails domain classes.